# Swift Gesture Recognizer on parent View without affecting the child View

Tags: ios, swift

i am developing a pop-up screen that has a transparent background on it, i want to dismiss the pop-up VC by clicking only the transparent background, but when i click on the pop-up View, it also dismisses the VC, that is because the subviews in parent view also has the gesture recognizer.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the Gesture Recognizer with UIButton and makesure the button is behind the child view